# Converting list of tuples into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm looking for a way to convert a list of tuples like this:

```
[(1,4),(2,4),(3,4),(4,15),(5,15),(6,23),(7,23),(8,23),(9,15),(10,23),(11,15),(12,15)]
```

into a dictionary like this:

```
{4:[1,2,3] ,15:[4,5,9,11,12], 23:[6,7,8,10]}
```

The second element from each tuple becomes a dictionary key, and all the first tuple elements associated with that key are stored in a value list.

Can you show me how that can be done?

Comment: Why would you want a list of dictionaries where each dictionary has only one key/value?  Are you sure you don't just want one dictionary?

Comment: Yes, you were right FogleBird. I was looking for dictionary eventually. Thank you for pointing that out...

Comment: Judging by the number of views, most people (like myself) got here looking for how to convert `myList = [(key1, val1), (key2, val2), ...]` to a dict: `{key1:val1, key2:val2...}`.
For this, just do `dict(myList)`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> l= [(1,4),(2,4),(3,4),(4,15),(5,15),(6,23),(7,23),(8,23),(9,15),(10,23),(11,15),(12,15)]
>>> d= defaultdict( list )
>>> for v, k in l:
...     d[k].append(v)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {23: [6, 7, 8, 10], 4: [1, 2, 3], 15: [4, 5, 9, 11, 12]})
>>> [ {k:d[k]} for k in sorted(d) ]
[{4: [1, 2, 3]}, {15: [4, 5, 9, 11, 12]}, {23: [6, 7, 8, 10]}]
```

Comment: +1 for using defaultdict. Much smoother than calling `setdefault()` each time.

Comment: Love collections.defaultdict. it's my go-to class for lots of work.

Answer (score 14):

```
>>> a = [(1,4),(2,4),(3,4),(4,15),(5,15),(6,23),(7,23),(8,23),(9,15),(10,23),(11,15),(12,15)]
>>> b = {}
>>> for i, j in a:
...     b.setdefault(j, []).append(i)
...
>>> b
{23: [6, 7, 8, 10], 4: [1, 2, 3], 15: [4, 5, 9, 11, 12]}
>>>
```

Comment: Brilliant! I just learned a new dict operation today - setdefault. That will tidy up my code a bit! Cheers. +1

Comment: @Steve Folly: Look at collections.defaultdict.  It's Even Better.

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [(1,4),(2,4),(3,4),(4,15),(5,15),(6,23),(7,23),(8,23),(9,15),(10,23),(11,15),(12,15)]
d = {}
for v, k in l:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Comment: By copying my use of setdefault in your edit, there are now fewer options for voters to choose from...

Comment: I really did not copy it. I realised I could use setdefault as well just after posting and updated by post because I liked it better.

Comment: No problem.  It's not wrong to edit to add others ideas anyway, but usually it's done to add more info, not create a duplicate answer.  But I understand that you did not copy mine.

Answer (score 2):

```
tuples = [(1,4),(2,4),(3,4),(4,15),(5,15),(6,23),(7,23),(8,23),(9,15),(10,23),(11,15),(12,15)]
dicts = {}
for elem in tuples:
    try:
        dicts[elem[1]].append(elem[0])
    except KeyError:
        dicts[elem[1]] = [elem[0],]
```

Comment: Use unpacking in your for loop.  And no need for a comma in a one-item list (only tuples).  And using an exception here is more okay in Python than other languages but still a little silly in this case.

Comment: The exception is not silly - it's how defaultdict does it.  I agree about the unpacking though.

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def to_list_of_dicts(list_of_tuples):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for x, y in list_of_tuples:
        d[y].append(x)
    return sorted([{x: y} for (x, y) in d.items()])
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not fancy but it is simple

```
l = [(1,4),(2,4),(3,4),(4,15),(5,15),(6,23),(7,23),(8,23),(9,15),(10,23),(11,15),(12,15)]
d = dict((k, [i[0] for i in l if i[1] == k]) for k in frozenset(j[1] for j in l))
```

Huzzah!

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in tuples:
    if d.get(key):
        d[key].append(value)
        continue
    d[key] =[value]
```