# Django get a list of related id's linked to each parent record id in a query set?

Tags: django

I have a relationship client has many projects.

I want to create a dictionary of the form:

```
{
    'client_id': ['project_id1', 'project_id2'],
    'client_id2': ['project_id7', 'project_id8'],
}
```

what I tried was;

```
clients_projects = Client.objects.values_list('id', 'project__id')
```

which gave me:

```
<QuerySet [(3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 11), (3, 12), (2, 3), (2, 13), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 6), (1, 10)]>
```

which I can cast to a list with `list(clients_projects)`:

```
[(3, 4),
 (3, 5),
 (3, 11),
 (3, 12),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 13),
 (4, 7),
 (4, 8),
 (4, 9),
 (1, 1),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 6),
 (1, 10)]
```

Comment: Hey @surfer190, I was wondering, did you find any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `projects` is the `ReverseManyToOneDescriptor` attached to the `Client` model, you can write that:

```
clients_projects = { c.id : c.projects.values_list('id', flat=True) for c in Client.objects.all() }
```

Comment: I used my solution along with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233546/python-converting-list-of-tuples-into-a-dictionary#answer-1233588...I wonder if your solution is faster

Answer (score 1):

This problem is quite similar to this one: [Django GROUP BY field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163299/django-group-by-field-value).
Since Django doesn't provide a group_by (yet) you need to manually replicate the behavior:

```
result = {}
for client in Client.objects.all().distinct():
    result[client.id] = Client.objects.filter(id=client.id)
                                      .values_list('project__id', flat=True)
```

**Breakdown:**

- Get a set of distinct clients from you `Client` model and iterate through them.
  (*You can also order that set if you wish, by adding `.order_by('id')` for example*)
- Because you need only the `project__id` as a list, you can utilize [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)'s `flat=True` argument, which returns a list of values.
- Finally, `result` will look like this:

  ```
  {
      'client_1_id': [1, 10, ...],
      'client_5_id': [2, 5, ...],
      ...
  }
  ```

---

There is a module that claims to add GROUP BY functionality to Django: https://github.com/kako-nawao/django-group-by, but I haven't used it so I just list it here and not actually recommend it.