# create nested dict from nested list python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to convert a list of lists into a nested dict.
The nested list looks like this (list of lists containing dates):

```
[[11, 'January', 2021],
 [12, 'January', 2021],
 [13, 'January', 2021],
 .
 .
 .
 [13, 'June', 2022],
 [14, 'June', 2022],
 [15, 'June', 2022]]
```

the goal is the following:

```
{2021:{'January':[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,....],'February':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,....],'March':....},
 2022:{'January':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,....],'February':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,....],'March':....}
 }
```

i'm totally stuck and not able to figure it out. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just wanted some clarity.

are you getting this from file, from API response ?
any special case in dates, e.g i can see in expected result January is having dates starting form 11,
What you have tried, any pseudo code?

Comment: IS the data sorted by month and year?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting list of tuples into a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233546/converting-list-of-tuples-into-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the many approaches:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json
dates = [[11, 'January', 2021],
 [12, 'January', 2021],
 [13, 'January', 2021],
 [13, 'June', 2022],
 [14, 'June', 2022],
 [15, 'June', 2022]]
 
out = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for date in dates:
    d, month, year = date
    out[year][month].append(d)
    
print (json.dumps(out))
```

Output:

```
{"2021": {"January": [11, 12, 13]}, "2022": {"June": [13, 14, 15]}}
```

Comment: Are there any other ways to make that a normal dict without `json.dump()`?

Comment: Have just added json to print it, else the `dict` is already created as `out`. If you just do `print(out)` that will also work

Comment: thank you very much :) That is exactily what I needed!

Comment: Cool! Glad that I could help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using a dictionary comprehension and `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

{year: {month: list(zip(*v))[0] for month, v in groupby(x, lambda x: x[1])}
 for year, x in groupby(sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[2], x[1])), key=lambda x: x[2])
}
```

output (I changed one January to February) :

```
{2021: {'February': (13,), 'January': (11, 12)}, 2022: {'June': (13, 14, 15)}}
```

Comment: More concise, but probably not better to maintain as it might be quite hard to understand.

Comment: @bastantoine Yes I agree, I'd personally go with the other answer ;)

Comment: Ahah you posted ii simply for the beauty of finding an answer way shorter then? ^^

Comment: @bastantoine I don't know about the beauty, but yes, I like to find solutions as comprehensions and/or with itertools :p

Answer (score -2):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

ans = [
 [11, 'January', 2021],
 [12, 'January', 2021],
 [13, 'January', 2021],
 [13, 'June', 2022],
 [14, 'June', 2022],
 [15, 'June', 2022]
]

finalDict = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))

for day, month, year in ans:
    finalDict[year][month].append(day)

print(finalDict)
```

Comment: Did you just copy/paste @Bhagyesh Dudhediya's answer, just removed the `json.dump()`?

Comment: Yup looks very much like it

Comment: No, I haven't copied his answer. Please consider the time of submission, we both submitted at almost (3 mins difference) same time. But still sorry, next time I will check before submitting any answer.